# Hosting WCF service on azure

Tags: wcf, azure

I got a wcf service which I'd like to run on azure, but I got several problems:

First: do I choose a web role or a worker role for running the wcf service?

Second: The client uses a call to log into the service, afterwards the service should remember who is logged in (sessions). The problem is, for firewall reasons I probably should use some http-binding. But these seem not to support sessions??
Or do I need AppFabric for sessions (what is AppFabric anyway?)?

Is there a good complete tutorial how to host wcf service?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you host your WCF service in a Web role, you'll then have all the benefits of IIS (pooling, caching, logging, etc.). You can rely on the WCF Web Role template and simply add a WCF service (which manifests itself as an svc) - and with the new SDK 1.3, you should be able to host a WCF service alongside your website in the same role.

You can also new up a ServiceHost in a worker role. With the worker role, you'll have complete control, but you'll lose the benefits of IIS.

For WCF labs, start with the [Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en). You'll see labs for:

- Hosting WCF in a worker role
- Using identity management for WCF security
- Using WCF with the service bus

Answer (score 4):

1. You will need to create web role for WCF service.
2. [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/51/) is a good tutorial on hosting wcf service on azure. I followed it and I could host a service on azure.
3. AppFabric is like a bus, which you can use for user authentication or getting some data from azure application.

Comment: You don't need to create a web role for a WCF service; a worker role works fine.

Comment: The example is nice, but uses BasicHttpBinding which is not secure enough for us. And when we try to replace the binding everything falls apart :(

Answer (score 3):

You can even host your WCF service on Azure Websites instead of using Web role or worker role.   See the details [here](http://genuinebasil.com/blog/?p=360).

Comment: Any limitation to that? Can I use the Azure Scheduler to call my WCF service hosted into a website to act like a SQL Agent?

Answer (score 0):

there´s no right answer for every scenario.
if your service is simple, and dont need to manage a lot of configurarions such as specific permissions and etc, the azure website may attend well.