# Custom web service to test android client app

Tags: android, web-services, rest, testing

i wonder if there is kind of free web service, where i can add my simple server application which will answer for requests of my android app... i need this for testing purposes. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is! If you are using the [KSoap](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/) library, [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/) is a tutorial for creating and testing a webservice which will convert celsius to farenheit and back again.

**Edit after some comments by the thread starter**

If you have written your webservice by yourself and want to host it, I recommend to use IIS under windows, if the service is written in WCF

[Introduction to IIS 7.5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290238/Getting-Started-with-IIS-7-5-and-ASP-NET-2-0-Class)

You could also host the webservice on Windows Azure

[Stackoverflow post regarding this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312343/hosting-wcf-service-on-azure)

Comment: He is looking for a site which provides a free webservice, not how to use a webservice.

Comment: exactly... i have simple testing webservice which should answer on my android client requests and i need some place to run it on

Comment: ah, so you want to host a webservice? Is the webservice written in WCF?